# Clipboard conflict when connected to remote desktop

Tags: python, clipboard, pyautogui, rdp

I am running a software in an infinite loop in my remote desktop pc and it copies and pastes stuff to variables every couple minutes and when I am connected to that RDP, my clipboard becomes same, if RDP copies 500, my clipboard becomes 500 in my actual pc, when I paste, I paste 500 and it's really annoying. Same goes for otherwise like if I copy 1000 in my actual pc, sometimes important variables that running in RDP becomes 1000 when RDP pastes it's (like I said it's same with my actual pc for some reason) clipboard to a variable. How can I seperate the clipboards of my pc and the RDP? Hope the issue is clear. Thanks.

I am using pyautogui and it has key presses of ctrl c and ctrl v. But the script isn't running on my pc. It's running in the RDP.

Comment: Before establishing the rdp connection, click "show options". In the "Local Resources" tab, uncheck clipboard

Comment: @PG11 wow I totally forgot about those settings. Thanks a lot.